# Plotting and Animating Spherical Spring Pendulum

Tags: differential-equations, physics

first post and somewhat new to Mathematica. Extremely new to making animations in Mathematica. My goal is to make a 3D animation of a Spherical Spring Pendulum system for a personal project. I received help and added the 'First' function when evaluating my functions {x[t],y[t],z[t]}, which helped me plot the path of motion. Now what I am struggling with is plotting the path along with the 3D animation I created at the same time. Also, if anyone would be able to help me make the pendulum rope look like a spring I would greatly appreciate. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer !

```
(* Defining Constants *)
g = 9.81;
m = 2;
k = 5;
r0 = 1;
\[Phi]0 = (Pi/2);
\[Theta]0 = (Pi/2);
r1 = 0.5;
\[Phi]1 = 0.1;
\[Theta]1 = Pi;


(* Solving Equations of Motion *)

Solutions = 
  NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[
      t] == (Sin[\[Theta][t]]*
      Cos[\[Theta][t]]*(\[Phi]'[t]^2)) - ((g*Sin[\[Theta][t]])/
        r[t]) - ((2*r'[t]*\[Theta]'[t])/r[t]), 
    r''[t] == ( 
       r[t]*(\[Theta]'[t]^2)) + ((r[t]*(Sin[\[Theta][t]]^2))*(\
[Phi]'[
           t]^2)) + g*Cos[\[Theta][t]] - ((k/m)*(r[t] - 1)), \[Phi]''[
  t] == -\[Phi]'[t]*((2*r'[t])/(r[t])) - (2*
    Cot[\[Theta][t]]*\[Theta]'[t]*\[Phi]'[t]), 
r[0] == r0, \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]0, \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]0, 
r'[0] == r1, \[Phi]'[0] == \[Phi]1, \[Theta]'[0] == \[Theta]1}, {r, \[Phi], \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 60}];

x[t_] := First[Evaluate[(r[t]*(Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Phi][t]])) /. Solutions]]
y[t_] := First[Evaluate[(r[t]*Sin[\[Phi][t]]*Sin[\[Theta][t]]) /. Solutions]]
z[t_] := First[Evaluate[-(r[t]*Cos[\[Theta][t]]) /. Solutions]]


(* Plotting Path *)

Motion = Table[ ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, MeshStyle -> None, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Boxed -> True], {tmax, 0.1, 
30, .1}];

(* 3D Animation *)
Animate[Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[.03], 
 Point[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}]}, {Black, PointSize[.01], 
 Point[{0, 0, 0}]}, {Black, PointSize[.01], 
 Point[{0, 0, 
   5}]}, {Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}]}, {Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {x[t], 
    y[t], z[t]}}]}}],PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},Boxed -> True], {t, 0.1, 40, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Try evaluating e.g. `{x[0], y[0], z[0]}` and you'll see that you have a list in the format `{{x}, {y}, {z}}` while the format you want to have, for `ParametricPlot3D`, is `{x, y, z}`. You can solve this by wrapping `Evaluate` with `First` in your definitions for `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Comment: You can use `Show` to combine `ParametricPlot3D` and `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 5):

```
g = 9.81;
m = 2;
k = 5;
r0 = 1;
\[Phi]0 = (Pi/2);
\[Theta]0 = (Pi/2);
r1 = 0.5;
\[Phi]1 = 0.1;
\[Theta]1 = Pi;
eq = {\[Theta]''[t] == 
    Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Theta][t]]*\[Phi]'[t]^2 - 
     g*Sin[\[Theta][t]]/r[t] - 2*r'[t]*\[Theta]'[t]/r[t], 
   r''[t] == 
    r[t]*\[Theta]'[t]^2 + (r[t]*(Sin[\[Theta][t]]^2)*\[Phi]'[t]^2) + 
     g*Cos[\[Theta][t]] - (k/m)*(r[t] - 1), \[Phi]''[
     t] == -\[Phi]'[t]*2*r'[t]/r[t] - 
     2*Cot[\[Theta][t]]*\[Theta]'[t]*\[Phi]'[t]};
ic = {r[0] == r0, \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]0, \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]0, 
   r'[0] == r1, \[Phi]'[0] == \[Phi]1, \[Theta]'[0] == \[Theta]1};

Solutions = 
 Flatten[NDSolve[{eq, ic}, {r, \[Phi], \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 60}]]

x[t_] := Evaluate[r[t]*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Phi][t]] /. Solutions]
y[t_] := Evaluate[r[t]*Sin[\[Phi][t]]*Sin[\[Theta][t]] /. Solutions]
z[t_] := Evaluate[-r[t]*Cos[\[Theta][t]] /. Solutions]
ListAnimate[
 Table[Show[
   Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[.03], 
      Point[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}]}, {Black, PointSize[.01], 
      Point[{0, 0, 0}]}, {Black, PointSize[.01], 
      Point[{0, 0, 
        2}]}, {Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}]}, {Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {x[t],
          y[t], z[t]}}]}}], PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-11, 2}},
    Boxed -> True], {t, 0.1, 40, 0.1}]]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Yes Alex Trounev, Thank you so much! I was able to get the 3D plot working eventually but your method seems much cleaner. Do you know of a way to make the pendulum string look like a spring or coil?

Comment: Should it be a deformable spring or not?

Comment: Yeah, if it could look like its stretching as it goes up and down with x[t],y[t], and z[t] that would be great !